# How to free a dynamically allocated array of structs in c?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am learning C and I can't free a dynamically allocated array of structs.
Here is my sample code:

```
typedef char Str50[50];

typedef struct exam {
    Str50 firstname;
    Str50 lastname;
    Str50 className;
    int score;
    Str50 date;
} Exam;

Exam *examDB

size_t allocateAndFreeTheStructArray {

    size_t numRecs = 100; //let's say the array contains 100 elements
    examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); //this allocates the needed memory

    // the code below tries to free what malloc allocated
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numRecs; i++) {
        free(&examDB[i]);
    }
    free(examDB);
}
```

When I compile this for windows, everything works fine (it seems). When I compile the same piece of code on my mac using xcode, I get an error that says:
"malloc: *** error for object 0x7fae610060d0: pointer being freed was not allocated"

How is that possible? I used malloc to create the array... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You allocated a flat array of 100 objects. You're then trying to free each object separately and the list at the end - that's a pattern used when you have an array of pointers to objects. In your case, you can't `free` just one object in a flat array.

You have two options. Keep the flat array and just call `free` once:

```
size_t numRecs = 100; 
examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); 

free(examDB);
```

Or change `examDB` to a pointer to pointer to `Exam` to keep a list of pointers:

```
Exam **examDB;
```

and then this would be the valid code:

```
size_t numRecs = 100; 
examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); 

for (size_t i = 0; i < numRecs; i++) {
    examDB[i] = malloc(sizeof ** examDB);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < numRecs; i++) {
    free(&examDB[i]);
}
free(examDB);
```

BTW, this must be one of the most confusing malloc invocations I've ever seen:

```
malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB)
```

Comment: This line `examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); ` is confusing. You meant `examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof (*examDB) ); `. Right ?

Comment: Yes, but it's taken from the question as-is.

Comment: Guys look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2):

You need a `free` for each `malloc`. How many `malloc`s you have? 1, so how many `free` you need? Just 1.

You are allocating an array of `100 * sizeof(examDB)` elements, which is dynamic but each element is a `examDB`, not a pointer to an `examDB` so you just need to free the whole array.

You would have required to free each element of the array if you had something like

```
// 1 malloc
examDB** array = malloc(sizeof(examDB*) * 100);

// 100 malloc
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  examDB[i] = malloc(sizeof(examDB));

...

// 100 free
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  free(examDB[i]);

// 1 free
free(examDB);
```

Answer (score 2):

You allocated an array of objects.  You can't free them by elements.  What you can do is just free `examDB` itself:

```
 free(examDB);
```

The reason to do this is, as I said before, you are allocating a whole array of null values, as this code you posted states:

```
examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB);
```

What you can do to free element by element is to initialize your allocated elements like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  examDB[i] = malloc(sizeof(examDB));
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) is a C++ reference for `malloc`.

**Tip**: I have never seen this `malloc` invoked like this:

```
malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB);
```

It's more common to put it this way:

```
malloc(numRecs * sizeof(examDB));
```

Comment: I agree, rhis 'style': `malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB);` is an abomination.

Answer (score 0):

```
examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); //this allocates the needed memory
```

This expression allocates a single contiguous block of `numRecs` * `sizeof *examDB`, and `sizeof *examDB` is the same as `sizeof struct exam`. So at this point you can *use* `examDB` much in the same way as if it was declared `struct exam examDB[numRecs]`.

Calls to `free` should be paired with calls to `malloc` and since you only `malloc` once, you only need to `free` once.

```
 examDB = malloc(numRecs * sizeof * examDB); //this allocates the needed memory
 //...
 free(examDB);
```